# Language Accepted by a Turing Machine with a Useless State?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, reductions, undecidability

What language is accepted by a Turing machine which has a state that it does not enter on input I?

Specifically,

1.If the accept state is the state that it never enters then should L={empty}?

2.If the reject state is the state that it never enters then should L={everything}?

3.What if the TM has multiple accept/reject states?

4.What if the state that it never enters is neither the reject nor accept states? How does that affect L?

I have searched around and I have found a couple threads that helped prove that this problem is undecidable but is it Turing-recognizable? Co-Turing Recognizable? Both?

Comment: *This problem is undecidable* – which problem? You seem to be asking two different questions. The first, what is the semantics of TMs with useless states. The second, can we determine whether a TM has a useless state. The usual rule is one question per post. I only answered your first question.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the language accepted by a Turing machine is valid for *all* Turing machines, whether they have useless states or not. Absolutely nothing changes. If there is a useless state, removing it wouldn't change the language accepted by the machine, as does adding another useless state.

Consider a similar question about C programs. What if I have a function which is never called? Does this affect the way the program executes? It doesn't.<sup>1</sup> The same holds for Turing machines.

<sup>1</sup>Actually it might, since you might run out of memory a tiny bit faster.